# export default curry function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I'm working in a SPA with a global store (Vuex), and i'm coding the services/utils to consume a data source. is the following approach exporting the default curry function is right?

```js
const curryFuction1 = (token) => async (params) => {
    // CODE
}
const curryFuction2 = (token) => async (params) => {
    // CODE
}

export default (token) => ({
  moduleCurryFunction1: curryFuction1(token),
  moduleCurryFunction2: curryFuction2(token),
});

// Consumed as following:

const result = await MyModule(token).moduleCurryFunction1(params)
```

Comment: are you facing any error?

Comment: What do you mean? It's syntactically correct. It would work by exporting functions. Whether it would export what you expect, I do not know.

Comment: how do you want to use it ?

Comment: My question is if this approach is correct, i mean the syntax is right and is working but im not sure if is the best way to export and consume a currying function.

Comment: Assuming this *is* what you want to do, then yes - there is no problem to have `f :: a -> b -> x` and export `f(a)` from the module. You're just left importing `g :: b -> x` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ ! i'm starting to use currying.